# when not overriding an abstract method in a child class I am not getting an exception thrown

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-class

When running the following code I am expecting to get an exception thrown because ChildPizza is inheriting from BasePizza but is not implementing the abstract method get_radius. But the program runs with no errors. Why?

At the very least the last line should throw an exception.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class BasePizza(object):
    __metaclass__  = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def get_radius(self):
        raise NotImplementedError( "implement me in child class" )

class ChildPizza(BasePizza):
    pass

myChildPizza = ChildPizza() 
myBasePizza = BasePizza()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3 doesn't use the `__metaclass__` class attribute, so you aren't actually defining an abstract base class. Instead, you specify a keyword "argument" to the class definition.

```
class BasePizza(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def get_radius(self):
        pass
```

You can also simply subclass `abc.ABC`, which is predefine to use `ABCMeta` as its metaclass.

```
class BasePizza(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get_radius(self):
        pass
```